# javascript If/Else Loop; async issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, async-await

Right now this section of code is passing along undefined to `if(customerWaiting >0)`. It's an issue with async that I can't seem to figure out.

Based off the other threads I looked at, it's very basic and a newbie question, I just can't make it work.

I was seeing if you could find it for me

Edit 1:

the goal of the code is to see if there are customers in the firebase "customerWaiting" database, if there is then display the modal, if there is not then say there are no customers waiting

```
structure for database is 
 customerWaiting
    -Automatically generated ID
     -customer information
```

Here is the code

```
 var customerWaiting;
 var employeeWaiting;


 var ref = firebase.database().ref();

 $("#connectNextUser").click(function() {
  {
    ref.child("customerWaiting").on("value", function(snapshot) {
      var customerWaiting = snapshot.numChildren();
      console.log("There are " + snapshot.numChildren() + " customers waiting");
    });
    ref.child("employeeWaiting").on("value", function(snapshot) {
      var employeeWaiting = snapshot.numChildren();
      console.log("There are " + snapshot.numChildren() + " employees waiting");
    });
  }
  if (customerWaiting > 0) {
    $("#myModal").modal();
    console.log("connect");
  } else {
    console.log("There are " + customerWaiting + " employees waiting");
    console.log("no connect");
  }
});
```

Comment: `customerWaiting` is declared locally, but used globally (in the click callback).

Comment: It's because `customerWaiting` is only defined within the `value` event handlers, not your outer `click` handler. It's hard to understand exactly what you're trying to achieve here, but I can tell you that nested event handlers are nearly always a bad idea. Could you provide a more detailed explanation of your goal, and also the code you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to do this:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref();

$("#connectNextUser").click(function() {
  // query how many customers are waiting
  ref.child("customerWaiting").on("value", function(snapshot) {
    // as soon as you have the result  then get the numChildren
    var customerWaiting = snapshot.numChildren();
    console.log("There are " + snapshot.numChildren() + " customers waiting");

    if (customerWaiting > 0) {
      // show the modal if customerWaiting > 0
      $("#myModal").modal();
      console.log("connect");
    } else {
      console.log("There are " + customerWaiting + " employees waiting");
      console.log("no connect");
    }
  });
});
```

If you want to use `await`/`async` then `ref.child("customerWaiting").on("value", resolve)` has to support Promises, or you need to convert it to one:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref();

$("#connectNextUser").click(async function() {

  var snapshot = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ref.child("customerWaiting").on("value", resolve)
    // you should also handle the error/reject case here.
  })

  var customerWaiting = snapshot.numChildren();
  console.log("There are " + snapshot.numChildren() + " customers waiting");

  if (customerWaiting > 0) {
    $("#myModal").modal();
    console.log("connect");
  } else {
    console.log("There are " + customerWaiting + " employees waiting");
    console.log("no connect");
  }
});
```